# Does adding a property to the end of a struct require a storage migration?

Tags: storage-migration

Does adding a property to the end of a struct used in a storagemap require a storage migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. It changes the length.

E.G. It can not decode a 6 bytes item from 4 bytes.